# docker run -e not working (before image name)

Tags: docker

I am trying to make a docker container for a game server.(first container i ever made) When i try to change de environment variable with the docker run command, the variables do not change in the container. My dockerfile:

```
 FROM ubuntu
 
 WORKDIR /
 
 RUN mkdir beammp
 
 WORKDIR /beammp
 
 ENV TZ=Europe/Brussels
 RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
 
 ENV \
     Version="v1.20-linux" \
     Debug="true" \
     Private="true" \
     Port="30814" \
     Cars="5" \
     MaxPlayers="10" \
     Map="/levels/east_coast_usa/info.json" \
     Name="test" \
     Desc="test" \
     use="Resources" \
     AuthKey=""
 
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
     git\
     make\
     cmake\
     g++\
     liblua5.3\
     libz-dev\
     rapidjson-dev\
     libcurl4-openssl-dev
 
 RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/BeamMP/BeamMP-Server
 
 WORKDIR /beammp/BeamMP-Server
 
 RUN git checkout tags/${Version}
 
 RUN cmake . && make
 
 RUN touch Server.cfg \
     && echo "# This is the BeamMP Server Configuration File v0.60" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Debug = ${Debug} # true or false to enable debug console output" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Private = ${Private} # Private?" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Port = ${Port} # Port to run the server on UDP and TCP" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Cars = ${Cars} # Max cars for every player" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "MaxPlayers = ${MaxPlayers} # Maximum Amount of Clients" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Map = \"${Map}\" # Default Map" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Name = \"${Name}\" # Server Name" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "Desc = \"${Desc}\" # Server Description" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "use = \"${use}\" # Resource file name" >> Server.cfg \
     && echo "AuthKey = \"${AuthKey}\" # Auth Key" >> Server.cfg
 
 EXPOSE 30814
 
 CMD [ "./BeamMP-Server" ]
```

Command I am trying:

```
 docker run --name beam -p 30814:30814 -e AuthKey='...' mastamic/beammp:0.1
```

Any pointers on how to optimize my dockerfile are always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AuthKey variable set in the `docker run` command will not affect the Server.cfg in the already created image from the `docker build`. At that point the image was already created with the file. You could solve that with a build arg, but that would result in what is normally a secret value and configuration data included in the image, which is an anti-pattern.

Instead, I'd probably start by running the `https://github.com/BeamMP/BeamMP-Server` in your current repo and checkout your desired tag there, making it a git submodule. When cloning your repo you'd then include submodules with `git clone --recurse-submodules`. Then the Dockerfile just has a copy of that directory.

After that, I would completely skip the creation of the Server.cfg inside of docker, or move that to an entrypoint that uses injected environment variables. Doing this outside of docker would involve creating the config file and mounting it as a volume. Performing the creation of this in the entrypoint could look like:

```
FROM ubuntu
 
WORKDIR /
 
RUN mkdir beammp
 
WORKDIR /beammp
 
ENV TZ=Europe/Brussels
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
 
ENV Version="v1.20-linux"
 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git\
    make\
    cmake\
    g++\
    liblua5.3\
    libz-dev\
    rapidjson-dev\
    libcurl4-openssl-dev
 
COPY BeamMP-Server/ /beammp/BeamMP-Server/
 
WORKDIR /beammp/BeamMP-Server
 
RUN cmake . && make
 
COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENV \
     Debug="true" \
     Private="true" \
     Port="30814" \
     Cars="5" \
     MaxPlayers="10" \
     Map="/levels/east_coast_usa/info.json" \
     Name="test" \
     Desc="test" \
     use="Resources" \
     AuthKey=""

EXPOSE 30814
CMD [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And then the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF >Server.cfg
# This is the BeamMP Server Configuration File v0.60
Debug = ${Debug} # true or false to enable debug console output
Private = ${Private} # Private?
Port = ${Port} # Port to run the server on UDP and TCP
Cars = ${Cars} # Max cars for every player
MaxPlayers = ${MaxPlayers} # Maximum Amount of Clients
Map = \"${Map}\" # Default Map
Name = \"${Name}\" # Server Name
Desc = \"${Desc}\" # Server Description
use = \"${use}\" # Resource file name
AuthKey = \"${AuthKey}\" # Auth Key
EOF

exec ./BeamMP-Server
```